# What is <span></span> element?

Tags: html

What is the purpose of the

```
<span></span>
```

element? And where should we use it?

Comment: Span is very CSS centric. It adds no markup on its own but it allows you to apply an ID, a style, or a class to a chunk of html. For example, instead of using <font face="Arial">some text</font> you would use <span style="font-family: Arial">some test</font>, or something similar.

Comment: @Wedge: little typo <span style="font-family: Arial">some test</font> should be <span style="font-family: Arial">some test</span>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered by any of the thousands of references online and it's about a particular coding issue.

Comment: j08691 - The [first hit on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+<span></span>+element>), which is http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp, states "A <span> element used to color a part of a text". I think there's a little more to it than that (but I'm not a web expert).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_span.asp):

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The  tag provides no visual
>   change by itself.
>
> The  tag provides a way to add a
>   hook to a part of a text or a part of
>   a document.
>
> When the text is hooked in a span
>   element you can add styles to the
>   content, or manipulate the content
>   with for example JavaScript.

So, the short version is, it's to style some text (without a paragraph or linebreak which is different from <div> tag)

Comment: +1. A typical example is to use it to make some text have a different background color (or any other element of style that does not have it's own HTML tag).

Comment: Isn't w3schools a bad reference to use?

Answer (score 7):

It is for grouping HTML elements and content for applying structure, defined for HTML 4.0 at
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4:

> The DIV and SPAN elements, in
>   conjunction with the id and class
>   attributes, offer a generic mechanism
>   for adding structure to documents.
>   These elements define content to be
>   inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) but
>   impose no other presentational idioms
>   on the content. Thus, authors may use
>   these elements in conjunction with
>   style sheets, the lang attribute,
>   etc., to tailor HTML to their own
>   needs and tastes.

It goes on to give an example of the usage.

Answer (score 6):

It's just a way to logically group subelements together.  You can also apply styles, etc at this level which will cascade down.

Take a look at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div) which goes into some depth.

Answer (score 5):

The span tag just tells the browser to apply what ever style changes are included within the span and if there is no styling within the span then there would be no formatting applied to the enclosed text. This is a bit different from the div tag which incorporates a paragraph break even if no styling options are included within a div.

So it is useful when you want to apply styles to elements without placing them in a separate block.

cheers

Answer (score 4):

Span has no structural meaning to the document (as h1 does, for instance), but can be used as a container when none of the other inline containers are appropiate. You would, for instance, use a span if you needed to apply some CSS to a small bit of text within some other text.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/span.html

Comment: what do you mean by structural meaning ?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to styling/grouping/scripting, spans can give actual functionality and/or meaning to bits of text. Consider these:

```
<p>This <span title="Punk IPA">beer</span> tastes good.</p>
<p>Come on, <span lang="kr">여보</span>!`</p> 
<p>Hello <span contenteditable="true">Wordl</span>!?</p>
```

Also the dir, translate or spellcheck attributes are not only for CSS or for JS, but usable on their own too!

Answer (score 2):

It's just a placeholder for javascript or css.

If you don't use javascript/css,  has no use to u.

Comment: Rubbish you can style spans if you so wish.

Comment: What so rubbish about, mP?

"It's just a placeholder for javascript or css." so anyone can manipulate it, IF he/she knows css/javascript.

Can u tell me, if he/she doesn't know about javascript/css, what does <span> mean to him/her?

And I didn't say it can't be styled. What I meant is <span> tag  only useful for those javascripter or css'er, for interactive design or graphic design.

Comment: Your answer is a bit deceiving. It is a placeholder element - like a div - with a difference of not being a block element - it is rendered as an inline element. It has no styling by default. Can be styled. Has no semantic meaning.

Comment: It could have post-processing meaning or it could be used to give some 100% HTML attributes too, like a title. Concider `<p>This <span title="Punk IPA">beer</span> tastes good.</p>". What about `Come on, <span lang="kr">여보</span>!` in a short story? Or `Hello <span contenteditable="true">Wordl</span>!`? Or the `dir` attribute? Or the `translate` attribute? Or the `spellcheck` attribute? All those are not JS and not CSS and definitely can be useful!