# How to change text in div without affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to modify the following HTML using Javascript,

```
<div id="1">
   some text
   <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `$('#1').text('new text');` However, this unintentionally removes `<div id="2">`

How should I change `some text`, without changing the surrounding elements?

Comment: `String.replace`? Put the text in its own element?

Answer (score 12):

This will change the value of the first [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) (which is a text node in your example):

```
$('#1').contents()[0].nodeValue = 'new text';
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jn6/)

Comment: downvote this answer doesn't work if there is tag or comment tag before the text (very shallow answer)

Comment: Hi @fareednamrouti, if you read the question, there is no tag or comment tag before the text. I also explicitly mention that this line will change the value of the *first node*, wherever that is a text node or a tag node or a comment node. But thanks for the suggestion, I added a link to the answer to make it even clearer.

Comment: the question clearly mentioned without changing the surrounding elements

Answer (score 0):

If plausible, do something like the following:

```
<div id="1">
   <span id="edit">some text</span>
   <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can edit your text like so:

```
$('#edit').text('new text');
```

Basically, your putting the text you want to edit in its own element with an ID. Keep in mind that you can use any type of element you want, you don't have to use `span` specifically. You can change this to `div` or `p`  and you'll still achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<div id="1">
   <span id='myspan'>some text</span>
   <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Then use;

```
$('#myspan').text('new text');
```

Comment: Why the downvote. Surely span is better than using a <p> tag given the question? See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096251/what-is-span-span-element .

Answer (score 0):

By the way it is a bad practice to use ids with numbers as elements.

You can add a span if you don't want to change the style of your element.
So in your case you will do something like this (I removed the numbers as ids):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="text-container">
     <span id="some-text">some text</span>
     <div id="something-else"></div>
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
//JavaScript
$('#some-text').text('new text');
```

Comment: It is fake code. I don't use numbers as ids. Also I have no possibility to add span element.

Comment: If you cant introduce new tags the check out @TrungDQ 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to check the node type as `Node.TEXT_NODE` and `nodeValue` is not null:

```
$('#1')
.contents()
.filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue && this.nodeValue.trim();
})
.replaceWith("new text");
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution as an alternative to others:

```
var text_to_keep = $('#2').text();

$('#1').text('new text').append('<div id="2">' + text_to_keep + '</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LM63t/

P.S. I don't think `id`'s that begin with a number are valid.