# What is the use of span tag?

Tags: html, css

I am a **beginner** and couldn't get the solution **Google** provided 
Basically I want to know what is the effect of span tag.

Comment: Why have you included all language tags but not html?

Comment: The question is off-topic but has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096251/what-is-span-span-element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey the span tag is used for format the html content inline like if you want to highlight the particular word/sentence from the paragraph.
here is the demo code for using span

```html
<p>
    ec quam felis, ultricies nec, <span style="background:blue">pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</span> Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapib
</p>
```